# Xcode 8.2: Unable to load configuration data from specified path / permission error in Mac OSX App:

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xctest

I have a Mac OSX app that I have previously been able to test - however when I run tests now - it will work once and then fail with the error below in the console.  I need to do some drastic things to get it working:

If I

1. change the location of my Derived Data folder
2. and clean build folder - then it will usually work again once or twice before but when I run tests again it will happen again.

Any ideas of what I can do to fix it permanently - below is pretty much Greek to me..

I have tried the following:

1. moving the derived data into Documents
2. installing new Xcode from Appstore.
3. Deleting and re-adding Certificates and profiles

> 2017-01-15 16:41:51.247064 XXXXXX[51736:892136] Unable to load
>   configuration data from specified path
>   /var/folders/59/7ylv57053bv3c0rbbcc1mcg40000gp/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/FDF2A461-45D7-4E64-B650-602DF0725CA7/remote-container/tmp/XXXXXXTests-FDF2A461-45D7-4E64-B650-602DF0725CA7.xctestconfiguration;
>   error: You don’t have permission. 2017-01-15 16:41:51.247221
>   XXXXXX[51736:892136] IDEBundleInjection Arguments: (
>       "/Users/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXX-eghnritsumpbbqgylbzrxqfximew/Build/Products/Debug/XXXXXX.app/Contents/MacOS/XXXXXX",
>       "-NSTreatUnknownArgumentsAsOpen",
>       NO,
>       "-ApplePersistenceIgnoreState",
>       YES ) 2017-01-15 16:41:51.248336 XXXXXX[51736:892136] IDEBundleInjection Environment: {
>       "APP_SANDBOX_CONTAINER_ID" = "com.XXXXXX.XXXXXX";
>       "Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render" = "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.hKPiBBDAAG/Render";
>       "CFFIXED_USER_HOME" = "/Users/XXXXX/Library/Containers/com.XXXXXX.XXXXXX/Data";
>       "DTX_CONNECTION_SERVICES_PATH" = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTXConnectionServices.framework";
>       "DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH" = "/Users/XXXXX/XXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXX-eghnritsumpbbqgylbzrxqfximew/Build/Products/Debug:/Users/XXXXX/XXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXX-eghnritsumpbbqgylbzrxqfximew/Build/Products/Debug:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks";
>       "DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES" = "";
>       "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" = "/Users/XXXXX/XXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXX-eghnritsumpbbqgylbzrxqfximew/Build/Products/Debug:/Users/XXXXX/XXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXX-eghnritsumpbbqgylbzrxqfximew/Build/Products/Debug:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks";
>       HOME = "/Users/XXXXX/Library/Containers/com.grant.XXXXXX/Data";
>       LOGNAME = XXXXX;
>       MallocNanoZone = 1;
>       NSUnbufferedIO = YES;
>       "OS_ACTIVITY_DT_MODE" = YES;
>       PATH = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin";
>       PWD = "/Users/XXXXX/XXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXX-eghnritsumpbbqgylbzrxqfximew/Build/Products/Debug";
>       SHELL = "/bin/bash";
>       "SSH_AUTH_SOCK" = "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.dNK7oacOAX/Listeners";
>       TMPDIR = "/var/folders/59/7ylv57053bv3c0rbbcc1mcg40000gp/T/com.grant.XXXXXX/";
>       USER = XXXXX;
>       XCInjectBundleInto = "/Users/XXXXX/XXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXX-eghnritsumpbbqgylbzrxqfximew/Build/Products/Debug/XXXXXX.app/Contents/MacOS/XXXXXX";
>       "XCODE_DBG_XPC_EXCLUSIONS" = "com.apple.dt.xctestSymbolicator";
>       XCTestConfigurationFilePath = "/var/folders/59/7ylv57053bv3c0rbbcc1mcg40000gp/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/FDF2A461-45D7-4E64-B650-602DF0725CA7/remote-container/tmp/XXXXXXTests-FDF2A461-45D7-4E64-B650-602DF0725CA7.xctestconfiguration";
>       "XPC_FLAGS" = 0x0;
>       "XPC_SERVICE_NAME" = "com.apple.dt.Xcode.23100";
>       "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING" = "0x1F6:0x0:0x2";
>       "__XCODE_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR_PATHS" = "/Users/XXXXX/XXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXX-eghnritsumpbbqgylbzrxqfximew/Build/Products/Debug";
>       "__XPC_DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH" = "/Users/XXXXX/XXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXX-eghnritsumpbbqgylbzrxqfximew/Build/Products/Debug";
>       "__XPC_DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" = "/Users/XXXXX/XXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXX-eghnritsumpbbqgylbzrxqfximew/Build/Products/Debug";
>   }

Comment: Are you admin on your computer? Or do you have any sort of security/management software running e.g. corporate machine management?

Comment: I am an admin -I don't have any corporate machine management software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have logged a bug with Apple as it appears that no one else is getting this error.

Edit: Elise has filed bug Apple #34737491, if you are experiencing it - then please raise a bug and reference that ticket so Apple can see how big the impact is.

Comment: Recently upgraded to Xcode 9 and now I'm getting it too. Did you hear anything from Apple yet?

Comment: Nothing at all - I think its more to do with xcode.  I am trying some other things - will update if I get a chance next week. Does your test run every 2nd time you try run it??

Comment: Yep! What I also noticed: when I run a specific test method, I get the 'no permission' error. When I then do 'Product > Test', i.e. all tests, they run fine. Then I can run specific tests for a while, until all of a sudden it's back to the 'no permission' thing.

Comment: I've filed a bug with Apple #34737491, if that's any use. If anything, it should bump this issue tiny bit higher up the bug-hierarchy.

Comment: I am seeing the same problem. I noticed that it only happens when testing inside a host application is enabled. (The topmost setting in the "General" tab of the test target.) If I test a framework without including the host application, everything works fine.

Comment: The "new build system" seems to solve this with Xcode 9.3

Comment: Nice one @adib - will try it

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 9 I found a solution, that worked for me.

Go to `Xcode` > `File` > `Project Settings...` (or `Workspace Settings...`)
Select `New Build System (Preview)` as Build System under Shared Settings.

Make sure to select `Use Shared Setting` under Per-User Project Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I too logged a bug with Apple. Experienced it on Xcode 9. However, I then played with it some more and found that by changing the Derived Data Folder to Custom and disabling code coverage in my Test config for my scheme, the error went away. It seems that some combination of these two caused the issue.

Comment: ...and it's failing again :( Guess it's just another temporary solution.

Comment: take a look at my solution, it might help.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason it went away on its own. If it happens again I will try it.